# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails on a Django generated MySQL table

Tags: python, mysql, sql-server, django

I am working on a django based project which created two tables `table1` and `table2` with a foreign key from `table2` to `table1`. I need to insert some values manually into `table2`. On trying to do so in MySQL I get the constraint failure error. I checked thoroughly, corresponding entries required for a foreign key constraint already exist in `table1`. I looked into some previous questions on SO but could not find an appropriate solution.

Table1 Schema:

```
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| email      | varchar(100)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
```

Table 2:

```
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| km          | varchar(1000) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| owner_id    | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| receiver_id | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The insert statement `insert into crest_recipient values(id,owner_id=5,receiver_id=5,km="hello world");`
 or similar ones fail with the exact error as

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (crest.crest_recipient CONSTRAINT
>   crest_recipient_owner_id_4943116a1387be04_fk_crest_user_id FOREIGN
>   KEY (owner_id) REFERENCES crest_user (id))

Comment: Can you post the schema, and the sample data for which the query is failing? It's hard to solve your problem with so little information.

Comment: That belongs in the Question area using [edit]

Comment: What does that error message mean to you ? Not that cryptic

Comment: a better output would be `show create table crest_recipient`, but the error message makes it obvious

Comment: Also update the *relevant* data and insert/update query for which it is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to update or insert a row in `crest.crest_recipient` table, a value in column `owner_id`

that does not exist in `crest_user` column `id`

### Edit

make it look like this

```
insert crest_recipient (km,owner_id,receiver_id) values ('test',5,1)
```

`'test',5,1` are whatever you want.

Skip the id column. Don't specify it, don't supply the value for it. It is an auto_increment PK most likely (basically there is nothing else it can be). The db engine chooses it for you. Specifying it will just screw things up 99% of the time.

**Focus on parameter 2 for now (the 5)**

Comment: I already mentioned that corresponding entries do exist in parent table already :-/

Comment: sorry, the db engine says it fails the RI that is in force. It is either lying to you, or it is late and you are tired. I would not dig my heels in the ground, if mysql questions weren't pretty much all I answer. RI=Referential Integrity, for those that don't know

Comment: I have 10k entries in `crest_user` and `id=5` is there so the given example query should not fail right ? But it does ? What could be the possible reason ? I don't think it is any sort of constraint violation, is it ?

Comment: it is definitely a constraint violation. See the Edit to Answer

Comment: Removing the `id` did the work for me :) However how does that violates the foreign key constraint ? Shouldn't it have raised some other related to `crest_recipient.id` column ?

Comment: Nah the db engine chooses the next auto inc for you so you let it

Comment: To me it was a malformed parameter passing with equal signs

Comment: If we are talking raw mysql queries that is

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert a row in child table crest_recipient which does not exist in parent table crest_user.

So first insert corresponding row in master table then you can insert in child table.